# Styling Spinner with another theme rather than current one

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-styles

I am currently using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` for my application. But since i don't like the default spinner's look , i wanna use `Theme.Holo.Light` spinner look for example.

How can i force a style for a certain widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout XML you can easily specify what style a View / widget has. So in your case you can chose the older Holo spinner style with the following style:

```
<Spinner
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. So it was that easy he.. I will commit suicide because of shame.